# Box Account Sync in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, sync

I am new to linux, I have currently installed kubuntu and I need assistance with synchronizing my box account to a folder in my Home. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I thought, it's a no-go.

[They **do not** support Linux, and do not plan to support it in the future](https://community.box.com/t5/Help-Forum/Sync-for-linux-environment/m-p/13148#M7427).

My suggestion is either to migrate to another Linux-friendly solution for your files, or change the OS that you are using and use Windows or Mac.

Comment: Wow, this is not good news for me. what about the davfs2 option? Do you Know about it?

Comment: "The" option seems only [one](https://github.com/jheld/diycrate) (from the comment in that discussion). Everything else (in particular the `davfs` things that you can find around) are 2-3 years old, so I believe that something changed and they do not work, nor are developed anymore.